# EMFILE too many open files in serverless deploy

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I'm having issues deploying my serverless application when I upgraded to windows 11. I tried to look for solutions like installing "serverless-plugin-common-excludes" and "serverless-plugin-include-dependencies" but failed.

Here is the error:

Cannot read file node_modules\rxjs\dist\types\internal\operators\publishLast.d.ts.map due to: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Users\renzo\ARCS\admin-service.build\node_modules\rxjs\dist\types\internal\operators\publishLast.d.ts.map'

[image]

Comment: please try to avoid error images